# Decomposing NURBS curve into piecewise Bezier segments

Tags: curves, polygons, rational-functions, bezier-curve

I have a question concerning a [paper](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1016/S0010-4485(01)00160-9). In it the authors try to approximate a NURBS curve by biarcs and to do so, they first need to find a polygonal approximation of the NURBS curve. They chose a geometric decomposition procedure which they begin defining as follows:

> The geometric decomposition is essentially a classical
> subdivision scheme based on the convex hull property of
> NURBS [6]. The process is outlined as follows.
>
> 1.Decompose the NURBS curve into piecewise Bezier
> segments.

Which already starts raising questions for me, how is it possible? Isn't the points of NURBS to produce curves which Bezier curves can not, like circles? Or should I assume that the Bezier curves the authors mention here are rational? And how one should perform such a decomposition?
The next steps in the procedure are also not exactly clear, but I am unable to post them here due to formatting difficulties. The part of text I am discussing can be found at page 3 of the article.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you very much and have a nice evening!

Comment: Yes, it should be rational Bezier curve. It is basically done by knot insertion multiple times at the two ends of the desired Bezier segment.